# Using php and html, how can I count the number of times a selection is made from a drop down list?

Tags: php

The program I'm working on is essentially a receipt maker for a restaurant. There is a drop down list which contains a bunch of foods taken from an array. The array includes the price for each item, and as of right now, the program will display any food item selected from the drop-down, list the individual prices, and add them up for a total. The problem I have is if someone selects the same item more than once, I have no way to register the quantity of said item. Basically, I need some code that checks the current selection against the past selections to see if their are any duplicates. I don't really know how to do that. [Here](https://gist.github.com/3881162) is my code so far. Please take a look and pass on any advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can store your selected values in a session and using the [in_array](https://www.php.net/is_array) function of PHP check if there already is a value of that selection in the session. Once the value is false, you can add the selection without duplicating an other value.

Edit;
Let's say you have an selectbox called item and you post on change. The value will be stored in $_POST['item'];

You can do this if the page is posted:

```php
<?PHP
if(!in_array($_POST['item'], $_SESSION['items'])) {
    $_SESSION['items'][] = $_POST['item']; // add posted item to array value items in session
}
?>
```

Don't forget the session_start(); on the very top of the page.

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Comment: [Here](https://gist.github.com/3881162) is my code with the two additional files referenced in the top of index. I'm new to php, and still unclear on sessions, but I think the session is already started in session.php.

Comment: I think you should do the check I gave you around line 31 of your index. If you using the value of the choice as a key, maybe you should use the array_key_exists function instead of the in_array.

Answer (score 0):

Use some sort of unique product ID for the array keys and before adding a new product into the array, possibly creating a duplicate, check if its ID already exists through the array key. If it exists, just run something like:

```
if (isset($products[$id]) {
    $products[$id]['quantity'] = $products[$id]['quantity']++;
} else {
    // Create new array item as you're doing now...
}
```